# How to group by table and create the new columns to put the original value in there?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgresql

```
type id n   occurred_at
A   159 4   2013/12/20 18:05
A   159 5   2013/12/27 18:05
A   159 6   2014/1/20 18:05
A   159 8   2014/3/22 12:34
B   180 5   2014/3/29 12:34
B   180 6   2014/4/22 12:34
C   207 4   2014/3/13 03:24
C   207 8   2014/3/20 03:24
C   207 6   2014/4/13 03:24
D   157 4   2013/12/20 18:07
D   157 5   2013/12/27 18:07
D   157 6   2014/1/20 18:07
D   157 8   2013/1/20 17:41
D   157 8   2013/12/27 17:41
D   157 8   2014/1/20 17:41
```

I want different `n` which has same `type` and `id` in one row and order by `occurred_at` (The `n` is only for 6 or 8). The result just like below, I was trying to use group by `type, id` to get this but seems difficult.
Does any guy have better ideas to do this?

```
A   159  6 8
B   180  6
C   207  8 6
D   157  8 8 6 8
```

Comment: so for D 157, the `6 8 8 8 ` as a space separated value?..

Comment: sorry I type wrong order by `occurred_at`, I want to create the new one column to set the order `n`.yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a space separated list of n-values, you can use `string_agg` to aggregate all values:

```
select type, id, string_agg(n::text, ' ' order by occurred_at) as n_values
from the_table
group by type, id;
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and it works. However, I have a few questions . I need to find which `type, id` with its `n_values` which string contain '8 6 8'  so I add ` having n_values like '%8 6 8%', it doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you want for the desired output, but if you are looking for a unique "n" value for each row based on the type and id, I think the `row_number()` analytic function would do that.

```
select
  type, id,
  row_number() over (partition by type, id order by occurred_at) as n,
  occurred_at
from my_table
```